# How to setup NPM package execution on Magento Cloud?

Tags: magento2, magento-cloud, npm

I need to run a command to compile my theme styles and commit them every time I need to push something new, these are the commands below.

```
npm i
gulp style
gulp js
```

When I try to run it via the Magento Cloud pipeline file, I got a permission issue to create folders and execute Gulp with the automated system.

How could I compile my styles via Magento Cloud pipelines?

Comment: I think you need to contact with Cloud Support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This new npm folder must be a **shared folder** as your var and pub folders are. To specify that your npm folder is a writable folder, you will need to edit your `magento.app.yaml` file.

```
 # The mounts that will be performed when the package is deployed.
mounts:
    "var": "shared:files/var"
    "app/etc": "shared:files/etc"
    "pub/media": "shared:files/media"
    "pub/static": "shared:files/static"
    "node_modules": "shared:files/node_modules"
```

In the same file, add Node to your **dependencies** section too.

```
ruby:
   sass: "~3.4"
nodejs:
   grunt-cli: "~0.3"
```

Create a bash file where you can easily execute all npm commands you need to run and add them into the build process like this example below.

```
hooks:
    build: |
        set -e
        npm config get prefix
        ./theme_compiler_install.sh
        ./theme_compiler.sh
        php ./vendor/bin/ece-tools cron:kill
        php ./vendor/bin/ece-tools build:generate
        php ./vendor/bin/ece-tools build:transfer
    deploy: |
        php ./vendor/bin/ece-tools deploy
    post_deploy: |
        php ./vendor/bin/ece-tools post-deploy
        php ./vendor/bin/ece-tools cron:unlock
```